# Use script "code ." in terminal to open PhpStorm

Tags: macos, terminal, phpstorm, code-editor

I want to type the script "code ." in terminal in order to open my code editor, PhpStorm. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using an alias with the `open` command?

Comment: I usually do script "open -a PhpStrom"  to open PhpStrom but I saw many developers on youtube can use script like "code ." to open their code editor so that I wanna use that script like them. It looks much better.

Comment: The `code` command comes with VS Code. Using it for another editor would be confusing. if you need an alias, I would use `phpstorm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `code` command is used to open VS Code specifically. PhpStorm doesn't come with a command-line interface, but you can create one by following this tutorial (you will need the Toolbox app in order to generate a shell script if an alias isn't enough for you): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html

Answer (score 0):

type code NameOftheProject and it will be open, make sure you are in the correct directory
forex  c:\composer\NameOftheProject> code NameOftheProject.